# toggle jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to toggle a button using jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $("#wp-admin-bar-maintenance").click( function() {
        var data = { action: 'maintenance' };

        $.post(maintenance.ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            $(".maintenance-icon").toggleClass('flicker');
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

That works, the button has the 'flicker' class and it's toggling, but now the PHP side messing it up.

```
function maintenance_adminbar() {
global $wp_admin_bar;

if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ){
    if(get_option( 'maintenance' ) == true) {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
            'id' => 'maintenance',
            'title' => __('Maintenance') . get_option('maintenance'),
            'href' => '#',
            'meta' => array(
                'class' => 'maintenance-icon flicker'
            )
        ));
    } else {
        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu(array(
            'id' => 'maintenance',
            'title' => __('Maintenance') . get_option('maintenance'),
            'href' => '#',
            'meta' => array(
                'class' => 'maintenance-icon'
            )
        ));
    }
}

}
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'maintenance_adminbar', 9999);
```

What this does is it adds a class called 'flicker' to the button using PHP when `get_option('maintenance')` is `true`.

But now the toggle function won't toggle anymore. When I click it, you can see it tries to toggle it but the flicker class from the PHP code is overriding it or something.

Is there any way to fix this up?

---

**Update.**

This is the ping function, which the AJAX function above uses;

```
function maintenance_process() {
    update_option('maintenance', !get_option('maintenance'));
    echo get_option('maintenance');
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_maintenance', 'maintenance_process');
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add a class to a button using PHP? PHP is server sided code. I don't see how this could ever work. Also, I'd like to see more of the code, because there are so many places this could go wrong (e.g. what is `maintenance.ajaxurl` and where is this set? What does your HTML look like?). I really don't see why you would try to do something like this with PHP, when it can easily be achieved with jQuery alone. If it's information from the server you need, get that info with a `$.get()` and then continue with jQuery.

Comment: @LaurensSwart Because when the user clicks the button, the button turns red. But when the user reloads the page, the button needs to stay red. My only option was to add the red class called 'flicker' to the element using PHP.

Comment: Why don't you save the state of the button in your database, or in a cookie, and let jQuery handle the toggle.

Comment: @LaurensSwart I feel like that's kinda unpredictable. I'm already saving the state of the button, `get_option('maintenance')` uses AJAX. When the button is clicked it can either returns `true` or `false` so I like to use that to check if the button needs to be red or default.

Comment: Is the button the actual admin menu item? Or is it a button elsewhere that you want to affect the admin menu item?

Comment: @Joe-NewNine The button is the actual admin menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make a few changes, but this is only based on my experience, workflow, and how I like to do things so I'll include notes and rationale for each.

**AJAX Call:** I like to set my ajax to return an actual value that I can read and react to in javascript, and I always (when possible) send it back as JSON because it's small and easy to parse.

```
<?php
function maintenance_process(){
    $maintenance = 1;
    if( 1 == get_option( 'maintenance' ) ){
        $maintenance = 0;
    }
    // I don't like using true/false in options and specifically
    // set the values to 1 or 0 for integer testing.
    update_option( 'maintenance', $maintenance );
    $result = array(
      'maintenance' => $maintenance
    );
    // Print JSON back to javascript
    exit( json_encode( $result ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_maintenance', 'maintenance_process' );
```

**JavaScript:** The JSON from ajax can now be read and used to toggle the class accordingly. In this case, we can read if maintenance is on or off from the Ajax call, and then set/remove our class. Also notice that I primed the `$.post` function to receive JSON with the added parameter at the end.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $( "#wp-admin-bar-maintenance" ).click( function( ev ){
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = { action: 'maintenance' };
        $.post( maintenance.ajaxurl, data, function( response ){
            if( 1 === response.maintenance ){
                $( ".maintenance-icon" ).addClass( 'flicker' );
            } else {
                $( ".maintenance-icon" ).removeClass( 'flicker' );
            }
        }, 'json' );
    } );
} );
```

**Admin Bar:** This code is fine but using my method, you would just change the `get_option` check to:

```
if( 1 == get_option( 'maintenance' ) ){...}
```

I'm not saying that my way of setting/passing variables is necessarily better, but it works extremely well for me across thousands of sites (custom themes and plugins). Now your javascript and admin bar code *can't* get out of sync because they're reacting to specific values passed back from ajax.

Let me know if this works or we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: I appreciate this! I've tried it out but it doesn't seem to be working. Do you mind me sending all the code I have to you so you can try it out and see the problem yourself?

Comment: Is your ajax firing? if you add `console.log( response )` to the `$.post` function, do you see the response and is it switching values when you click the button? If so, then the ajax is good and the option is changing, and we need to figure out what's next.

Comment: Yes, it's firing. The PHP toggler in `maintenance_process` doesn't seem to be working, though. It stays on true.

Comment: At the start of `maintenance_process`, add `delete_option( 'maintenance' )` and run it once. Then, get rid of that line. Let's delete the option entirely and start over. It's possible that it's not switching because it's reading the old true/false value and not switching.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, deleting the option resets it to `false` but once clicked, it stays on `true` and the issue is back again.

Comment: Change `1 === get_option( 'maintenance' )` to `1 == get_option( 'maintenance' )` (remove the third equals sign)

Comment: Ah! That works! Amazing. It finally works, after 4+ hours trying things out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help!